# Parse Json to String android studio

Tags: java, android, json

I have this JSON object:

```
{
  "1":{
    "id_module":"f83d6101cc",
    "adresse_mac":"00:6A:8E:16:C6:26",
    "mot_de_passe":"mp0001","name":"a"
  },  
  "2":{
    "id_module":"64eae5403b",
    "adresse_mac":"00:6A:8E:16:C6:26",
    "mot_de_passe":"mp0002",
    "name":"a"
  }
}
```

And I would like to parse and get to string `id_module`, `adresse_mac`, `mot_de_passe` and `name` for each thing the 1 and the 2.

So I made this but it's not working :

```
TextView txt1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
String ajout1 = "http://";
JSONObject json = null;
String str = "1";
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost(ajout1);
try {
    response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
    str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
    String MAC = jsonObject.getString("id_module");
    txt1.setText(MAC);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `str` is a `JSONObject`, not `JSONArray`

Comment: Make sure you are calling this on non GUI thread (new thread, AsyncTask,...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try this:

```
String str = "your json string";
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
String module = json.getJSONObject("1").getString("id_module");
String address = json.getJSONObject("1").getString("adresse_mac");
String module2 = json.getJSONObject("2").getString("id_module");  //from 2nd object
```