# I want to read this JSONArray,little confused..please guide me

Tags: android, arrays, json

How to read the images and its corresponding positions

```
 "images": [
  [
    {
      "images_url": "http://provenlogic.info/tinder_web/public/uploads/e9275d47cf5efd929794caafc50e957982c47582.jpg",
      "position": "1"
    },
    {
      "images_url": "http://provenlogic.info/tinder_web/public/uploads/c374561da8583a77b4d21ee4b06f30d1a3fac4bb.jpg",
      "position": "3"
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: provide Whole json please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Json to String android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302812/parse-json-to-string-android-studio)

Comment: Check this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/28304728/4169014

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = rootObject.getJSONArray("images");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String imageUrl=jsonObject.getString("images_url");
                String position=jsonObject.getString("position");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Happy Codding!!!

Answer (score 0):

A JSON Object starts with a { and ends with a } while a JSON Array starts with a [ and ends with a ].

```
JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("images").get;

for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length;i++)
{
   JSONObject jObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

   String imageUrl = jObj.getString("images_url");
   String position = jObj.getString("position");
}
```

You will need to wrap the whole JSON Handling inside a try/catch block. You might want to try http://jsonlint.com/, an online json validator and https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/, an online json formatter to understand easily!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> First of all get the JsonArray by using array name "images"
>
> and get each Json object .

```
try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("result");
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                JSONArray jsonArray1=jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
                for(int j=0;j<jsonArray1.length();j++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray1.getJSONObject(j);
                    String imageurl=jsonObject.getString("images_url");
                    String position=jsonObject.getString("position");
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```